# cudaArray vs. device pointer

Tags: arrays, cuda, textures

I am confused about the difference between the intended use of device pointers and `cudaArray` structures. Could someone please explain why I would use one versus the other? My basic problem is that after looking through documentation and reading the book "CUDA by Example," I do not understand the intent of the API designers.

From what I have seen, it seems that `cudaArray` should be used for textures and pointers should be used for directly accessing memory. It also seems that 3D textures can only be created using a `cudaArray`. Should all textures be allocated using `cudaArray`? Numerous examples seem not to. Also, why is there a function `cudaMallocArray` and `cudaMallocArray3D`, but no equivalent for `cudaMallocArray2D`? Conversely, there is a `cudaBindTexture` and `cudaBindTexture2D`, but no `cudaBindTexture3D`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`cudaArray` is an opaque block of memory that is optimized for binding to textures. Textures can use memory stored in a [space filling curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve), which allows for a better texture cache hit rate due to better 2D spatial locality. Copying data to a `cudaArray` will cause it to be formatted to such a curve.

So, storing data in a `cudaArray` is an optimization technique which can yield better texture cache hit rates. On early CUDA architectures, the `cudaArray` also cannot be accessed by a kernel. However, architectures of compute capability >= 2.0 can access the array via CUDA surfaces.

Determining if you should use a `cudaArray` or a regular buffer in global memory comes down to the intended usage and access patterns for the memory. It will be project specific.

`cudaMallocArray()` actually allocates a 2D array, so I think the issue is just inconsistent naming. Maybe it would have been more logical to call it `cudaMallocArray2D()`.

I haven't used 3D textures. Hopefully, someone will answer and let us know why there's no need for `cudaBindTexture3D()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use cudaBindTextureToArray, it works for both 2D and 3D.